# Child div conforming to viewport height, not parent div height

Tags: html, css

I have multiple wrapper divs, which contain an image each:

(img URL replaced with # for brevity)

```
<div class="grid-item"><img src=#><div class = "middle"><div class = "text"></div>Build the Big Delta 3D printer</div></div>

<div class="grid-item"><img src=#><div class = "middle"><div class = "text">3D printed Vacuum cleaner for CNC machine</div></div></div>

<div class="grid-item"><img src=#><div class = "middle"><div class = "text">How to make the BEST butter cookies!</div></div></div>
```

The parent divs ("grid-item") have the following styling:

```
.grid-item{
max-width: 1fr;
max-height: auto;
padding:0.6em;
}
```

and the child divs ("middle") have are styled as such:

```
.middle{
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
}
```

As I understand it, the "top: 50%" should shift the ".middle" div and all text contained within to the middle of the parent div, which is also the middle of each respective image.

However, it is shifting all text to the middle of the viewport. Leaving me with one line of overlaid text.

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Parent of absolute needs to be position:relative. Also top:50% will put top of your image at the center of div, not center it in the div.

Comment: Also `top:50%` doesn't necessarily do what you think it does.

Comment: If you explain what it is you are trying to do it would be helpful becuase I suspect you are making this more complicate than necessary.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Woah, such a quick fix. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Paulie_D want to shift the text in on div to the middle of a wrapper div, that contains a div with an image. i.e put text in the middle of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute` needs a relative container to hold it in.
If you want `.middle` to be absolute relative to .grid-item, you should include `.grid-item { position: relative }` to your css.